# Extraction Techniques for Organic Compounds from Aqueous Media

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, purification

I am looking to attempt an extraction of an organic compound that had just been prepared using a Friedel-Crafts acylation. The compound was prepared in MDC (~20 mL in total). After the reaction, the organic compound was poured into ~20 mL of ice-cold distilled water. The protocol I am referring to states

> "The reaction mass was cooled and water was added slowly under stirring condition. Product was extracted in MDC (12 X 2) and washed with water followed by treating with saturated sodium chloride solution (20 mL) ... "

I don't want to make any inferences as to what this means since I am new to synthetic lab work, but my guess is that it means 2 portions of 12 mL of MDC were used to separate the compound from the aqueous phase. I am not sure why they follow this by washing with water unless I am interpreting what "Extracted in MDC (12 X 2)" means. Similar sections in the paper include a little more detail that confirms my original speculations regarding what is meant by (12 X 2), but it still does not make sense to me why this would be followed by washing with water and not skip immediately to washing with a saturated NaCl solution. Here is the DOI to the paper: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.bmc.2018.05.016. The section I am looking at is 2.1.4.

Comment: Sorry for this seemingly trivial question. I am just looking to gain a more complete understanding of reading experimental sections, as I have not had much experience with this.

Comment: You are reasoning as if DCM and MDC are the same substance ? I am not sure. DCM may be dichloromethane. But MDC ?

Comment: MDC and DCM are the same (methylene dichloride and dichloromethane)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I did not realize that I used two different acronyms until I had posted the question. I will change it to be more clear.

Comment: The backwash with water is to remove any inorganics that may have been carried through into the DCM product solution. It is a good idea to keep all your aq wash fractions until you have isolated your product. If your yield is low that is where the rest of your product is.

Comment: Is the amount of DCM used in the reaction a big deal? The protocol just states that the reactant was dissolved in DCM (doesn't specify how much). I went with ~20 mL to dissolve the product in the reaction flask since this is about how much is used in the 2 consecutive 12 mL DCM washing steps.

Comment: The amount of DCM doesn't really matter as it will be removed under reduced pressure. I rather doubt they precisely added 12ml each time. 20ml washes would be perfectly OK